# Keyboard doesn't works on XFCE (but it works!)?

Tags: debian, keyboard, xfce, hardware

Before I formatted my notebook, the onboard keyboard worked perfectly on Debian 8 with Gnome 3.  Now, after installing Debian 9 with a minimal XFCE, it doesn't work anymore, except on CLI.

I can't even change to TTY because no keys work, except in recovery mode.

Here are some files that I collected about the keyboard settings:

`/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"  
XKBLAYOUT="br"  
XKBVARIANT=""  
XKBOPTIONS=""  

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

`/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input`:

```
mouse_drv.so synaptics_drv.so void_drv.so
```

I have installed the package `xserver-xorg-input-kbd` during the install, but decided remove it thinking that it was the problem. In both cases the keyboard doesn't work on XFCE.

And no, I don't use any session manager. I just automated the process [of login through the systemd and the .profile.](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=123694)

**Edit:** I installed the package xserver-xorg-input-libinput and the keyboard started to work on XFCE. Case closed. =)

Comment: Lets try to eliminate hardware failure first. Have you verified if any other keyboard would work? Or that your current Keyboard works with other systems?

Comment: It's a notebook keyboard brah. And no, I haven't another keyboard here to test. =\

Comment: So to clarify the keyboard worked in GNOME but now does not work when you installed a new OS with XFCE? What do you mean it only works in CLI? Also what do you mean by minimal? You most likely are missing the correct packages/drivers.

Comment: "So to clarify the keyboard worked in GNOME but now does not work when you installed a new OS with XFCE? What do you mean it only works in CLI?" **Yes**. "Also what do you mean by minimal? You most likely are missing the correct packages/drivers." I install the [minimal drivers](https://git.devuan.org/dev1fanboy/Upgrade-Install-Devuan/wikis/Minimal-xorg-install) and the core of XFCE.

Comment: I have edited the comment. Check it. The core of XFCE is something like [this](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/how-to-install-a-minimal-ubuntu-desktop/). And about the CLI: the keyboard works on console mode. Just this. I make all the minimal install on console using the keyboard.

Comment: Have you verified the checksums of your install media? Is there a reason you need to install XFCE that way? Can you use the version of Debian that ships with XFCE or select the XFCE desktop packages during a Debian netinstall?

Comment: "Have you verified the checksums of your install media?". **Yes**. "Is there a reason you need to install XFCE that way?" Even in the core meta-package of XFCE has some packages that I won't use. But the real reason why I have do this was for the learning. You are forced to learn more things on a minimal install from CLI.

Comment: I can respect that, however [there is a Debian way](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) of doing things. On the surface here it appears the core XFCE meta-package has the necessary drivers for your keyboard. Did you follow [these steps to install your system?](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apds03.html.en)

Comment: I didn't think so. I based my install on many "minimal install" tutorials who works for many people. I didn't see people complaining about the keyboard doesn't work. [Look at the packages](http://telegra.ph/XFCE-03-30) that I have installed and tell me if I missing something.

Comment: The guides you have linked are for Devuan and Xubuntu not Debian. There will be minor differences which could be the root cause of the issue. Without the complete output of `apt` telling you what packages are actually going to be installed from the command you are showing, I cannot say for certain if you are missing anything. I can look more into this after the weekend and  try to get back with a solution. The issue with "minimal" installs is one person's idea of minimal could be another's bloated nightmare. For example, a netinstall with XFCE is minimal to me.

Comment: I was inspired by different tutorials, but didn't follow them blindly. I have checked if all packages was present in Debian 9. But please, don't lose more your time with this. If I don't get an answer I will just formating the machine again with the standart XFCE. =)

Comment: I think I have the same issue, and would like to modify the question -- if indeed ~-input-libinput solves my problem (will try later today).  I installed vanilla Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver), and but wanted xubuntu, so installed xubuntu-desktop xorg x-something-i-forget.  Keyboard would not work (did not try init 3 yet). but mouse ok, and allowed onscreen kb to keep me in the game.  
--
So I think there is an issue to note for those trying side doors into Xfce.  I would like to identify exactly what the discrepancy is, and change the question to definitively ID and solve. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 4):

Just to make it clear what the answer is:
I was having a similar issue, and I also installed the package `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` as suggested and the keyboard started to work again.